# How to remove the "Failed Connecting to service" alert?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

My IBM Mobilefirst app connects to the server when its launched. When i try to open the app in offline mode it shows an alert with **"The Application failed connecting to the service"** with 3 buttons: "reload", "close" and "Details".

How to disable this alert when app is offline? I have tried not calling `WL.Client.connect` but didn't work. What is proper way to handle this?

From the log in Offline Mode:

```
04-06 15:54:21.578: E/NONE(16221): [/apps/services/api/app1_worklight/android/logout] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.

04-06 15:54:21.588: E/NONE(16221): Client init failed. The service is currently not available.
```

Comment: Can you provide the logs? Try to implement onConnectionFailure method in initoptions.js to capture the MF API failure. Read the followings questions [Server Connecting Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725835/ibm-worklight-6-1-server-connection-issue)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not calling `WL.Client.connect` there is **no way** you are still getting this when the device is connected to the Internet and you launch the application. That sounds like you didn't actually generate a new app not-containing the `connect` method.

I reproduced the mentioned dialog by using the `connectOnStartup` property in initOptions.js and shutting down the development server. *Note that this property is deprecated starting Worklight 6.2*.

As for the actual issue - not displaying the default failure dialog in case of a failed connect attempt, you have two options as I see it:

1. Don't use `connectOnStartup` in initOptions.js. Instead, in common\js\your-main.js use:

   ```
   function wlCommonInit() {
       WL.Client.connect ({onSuccess: successCallback, onFailure: failureCallback});
   }

   function successCallback() {
       ...
   }

   function failureCallback() {
       ...
   }
   ```

In case of a failed connect attempt, the `failureCallback` function will be called.

2. If you *are* using `connectOnStartup`, then in common\js\initOptions.js add the `onFailure` option. This will override the default behavior. The implementation will be like so:

   ```
   var wlInitOptions = {
       connectOnStartup:true,
       onFailure: function() {
           WL.App.hideSplashScreen();
           wlCommonInit();
       },
       ...
   }
   ```

Must be noted, though, that you are altering the application flow and by overriding the default flow you are now completely in charge or it and must make sure in your application that nothing unexpected is happening.

Also, Why do you want to remove this dialog? There is a Close button...

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it appears there is a call being made to logout from the MobileFirst server. Check your application code to ensure you are not making any calls to the MobileFirst server, not just connect.

Answer (score 0):

As per the log, logout request has been sent to server.

Since the device in offline mode, the request is getting failed.

I believe the following implementation will help you,

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WL.Client.connect ({onSuccess: successCallback, onFailure: failureCallback});
}

function successCallback() {
   if( WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("RealmName")){
      WL.Client.Logout("RealmName",{
            onSuccess:function(){},
            onFailure:function(){}
         }
      );
   }
}

function failureCallback() {
        ...
}
```

or

```
function wlCommonInit() {
   WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(
      function (networkInfo) {
         if (networkInfo.isNetworkConnected == "true") {
             if( WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("RealmName")){
                WL.Client.Logout("RealmName",{
                   onSuccess:function(){},
                   onFailure:function(){}
                });
             }
         } 
      }
   );
}
```

It's a sample snippet, you can customize the way you want to.

This [link](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/offline-authentication/)[*IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0*] will help you to understand, how to handle such a complex mechanism.